# object[index] - Javascript Object Error in IE - Object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: javascript

I have a simple script to retrieve an id from an object list in javascript.  Here is the example:

```
   var element_id;

    if (cur_index !== 0) {
        element_id = _BIG_LIST[cur_index-1];
    }
```

IE is throwing an error at:   _BIG_LIST[cur_index-1]

Error is Object doesn't support this property or method.  This works fine in other browsers, and _BIG_LIST is definitely populated.  Also cur_index is definitely within the _BIG_LIST object.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure that: 1. `_BIG_LIST` is an array?
2. `cur_index` is an integer?

Comment: var _BIG_LIST = [];

and yes cur_index is an integer, would be 0 - 50

Comment: in that case, debug. Try using the good old `alert()` just before the problem code line.

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed.  The var element_id was not in scope where i was using it, which caused IE to throw the error.